# How do I access to the value of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm trying to loop over a collection of objects and get the first value (breed). Like:

- Beagle
- Golden Retriever
- Corgi
- Goldendoodle
- Labrador Retriever

Right now I mapped over the data, but it just lists up each {}. How do I access inside of each {} ?

```
const data = [
    { 
        "breed": "Beagle",
        "characteristics": "playful" 
    },
    {
        "breed": "Golden Retriever", 
        "characteristics": "calm" 
    },
    {
        "breed": "Corgi", 
        "characteristics": "bright" 
    },
    {
        "breed": "Goldendoodle", 
        "characteristics": "gentle" 
    },
    {
        "breed": "Labrador Retriever", 
        "characteristics": "loyal" 
    },
]


data.map(item => {
    console.log(item);
})
// Object { breed: "Beagle", characteristics: "playful" }, Object { breed: "Golden Retriever", characteristics: "calm" }, ...
```

Comment: If you know the property you want to access, try `item.breed`. Also, `map` is used to transform the values in an array to a new array. If you're just iterating and using `console.log`, try `forEach` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the breed, extract the `breed` from each item.

```js
const data = [{"breed":"Beagle","characteristics":"playful"},{"breed":"Golden Retriever","characteristics":"calm"},{"breed":"Corgi","characteristics":"bright"},{"breed":"Goldendoodle","characteristics":"gentle"},{"breed":"Labrador Retriever","characteristics":"loyal"}];

const res = data.map(({ breed }) => breed);
console.log(res);
```

ES5 syntax:

```js
var data = [{"breed":"Beagle","characteristics":"playful"},{"breed":"Golden Retriever","characteristics":"calm"},{"breed":"Corgi","characteristics":"bright"},{"breed":"Goldendoodle","characteristics":"gentle"},{"breed":"Labrador Retriever","characteristics":"loyal"}];

var res = data.map(function(item) {
  return item.breed
});
console.log(res);
```

If you just want to log each item, use a `forEach` loop:

```js
const data = [{"breed":"Beagle","characteristics":"playful"},{"breed":"Golden Retriever","characteristics":"calm"},{"breed":"Corgi","characteristics":"bright"},{"breed":"Goldendoodle","characteristics":"gentle"},{"breed":"Labrador Retriever","characteristics":"loyal"}];

data.forEach(({ breed }) => console.log(breed));
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply:

```
data.map(item => {
    console.log(item.breed);
})
```